# How to convert images (GIF, JPG, JPEG, PNG) to TIFF in PHP?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

How can I convert images to .tiff with php? (im testing on win xp)

I remember I used imagemagick to do this but I cant find the code now, and couldnt find any example on google.

A code sample will be appreciated.

Also, is there a way to do it without imagemagick?

Comment: What about consulting the manual directly? http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php Instead of ImageMagick you could also use gd: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this links helps you, checkout this:

1. http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick
2. http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php,

Answer (score 4):

Following is the code sample that might be helpful for you.

```
<?php
try
{
  $image = new Imagick("testing.jpg");
  $image->writeImage("page.tiff");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: I doubt that an answer written half a year after the question was asked could be helpful to anyone. Removed a link, as, I suppose, it was the only reason to bother with post.

Comment: I have to disagree. Old is gold too, especially when most of the visitors find StackOverflow solutions via search engines.

Comment: it was painfull to install Imagick.... heres a link that worked for me: https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-php-imagemagick-on-centos-7